# x86 - Seeding a Random Number using the C Library

Tags: list, assembly, random, x86, random-seed

I am trying to seed the random function from the C-Library to get a truely random value. I tried using the extern 'rand', 'random', and 'srand'. Both rand and random give me the same results, and srand returns 0.

```
segment .data
  list: db 'rand %d', 1

segment .text
  extern printf, rand
  global main

main:
  call    rand
  mov     esi, eax
  mov     edi, list
  xor     eax, eax
  call    print f
  mov     rax, 0
  ret
```

I appreciate any hints to my problem. Thank you!

Comment: `srand` is used to seed the random number generator `rand` function. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/) is the documentation of the function.

Comment: You could use the RDTSC instruction to get a semi random value into _EAX_ and then pass that into `srand` as a seed at the beginning of your program (do it once at the beginning of your code). Then you just call `rand`  to get randoms value. Or you could call the `time` function to get a semi random value.

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?

Comment: We are doing this on a Ubuntu Linux server. x86_64

Comment: Thank you very much Michael. I used RDTSC to get a value in which I used to multiply with my random number that was generated by the rand function.

Comment: /facepalm.  Use `rdtsc` to get an input for `srand`, *then* you can use `rand` repeatedly to get a pseudo-random sequence.

Comment: If your CPU is recent enough, then use rdseed, otherwise rdrand.  If either doesn't set the carry flag, then fall back to rdtsc.

Comment: Thank you Peter and Jeremy!